# Como delegar métodos da interface automaticamente?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, método, interface

Criei esses métodos na interface:

```
public interface IEvents
    {
        void OnEscrever(string text);
        void OnEnable(bool b);
        void OnDisable(bool b);
    }
```

Vou ter algumas classes que irão Herdar esses métodos:

```
public class Herda1 : IEvents
    {
        public void OnDisable(bool b)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnEnable(bool b)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnEscrever(string text)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

public class Herda2 : IEvents
    {
        public void OnDisable(bool b)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnEnable(bool b)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnEscrever(string text)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Quero que cada método da classe `Herda1` e `Herda2` ou outras classes que herdarem `IEvents`, recebam valores por parâmetros.

Vamos imaginar o componente `Timer` do Windows Form, ele tem seu evento chamado `Timer1_Tick` por padrão, não posso ver como se desenrola o script desse controle internamente, só consigo puxar o valor através do parâmetro do método, ou pela instância.

E se eu quisesse jogar esse método na interface? E Todas as classes que herdarem essa interface, pudessem receber por parâmetro do método valores desenvolvido internamente? E esses métodos já fossem delegados por padrão?

Em java, eu usava (implements  Interface) para implementar os métodos. No C# não faço ideia como se faz.

Segue o meu raciocínio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que quando os métodos da interface forem implementados automaticamente, fiquem delegados em qualquer uma das classes verdes acima.
Isso é possível? Se sim, como?

Vamos supor o próprio evento do C#

```
    public delegate void Disable(bool b);
    public delegate void Enable(bool b);
    public delegate void OnEscrever(string text);

    public class ImplementaInterface : IEvents1 // efetua trabalho interno
    {
        public event Disable OnDisable;
        public event Enable OnEnable;
        public event OnEscrever OnEscrever;

        public ImplementaInterface()
        {
            this.OnDisable += new Disable(??????????); // eis a questão
            this.OnEnable += new Enable(??????????); // eis a questão
            this.OnEscrever += new OnEscrever(??????????); // eis a questão

            this.OnEnable(true);
            this.OnDisable(true);
            this.OnEscrever("Ola Mundo!");
        }
    }

    public interface IEvents1 // qualquer classe pode herdar essa interface
    {
        event Disable OnDisable;
        event Enable OnEnable;
        event OnEscrever OnEscrever;
    }

    public class Herda1 : IEvents1 // esta classe esta herdando a interface
    {
        public event Disable OnDisable; // isso não é método delegado
        public event Enable OnEnable;
        public event OnEscrever OnEscrever;
    }

    public class Herda2 : IEvents1 // esta também está herdando
    {
        public event Disable OnDisable;
        public event Enable OnEnable;
        public event OnEscrever OnEscrever;
    }
```

Percebam que coloquei na interface o operador `event`, quando alguma classe instanciar essa interface, não vai receber métodos,  mas sim variável o que não quero. Para entender, observem o comentário interrogação, é ali que vou querer delegar os métodos da interface.

O código não é 100%, mas é só aonde quero chegar.

Comment: Não entendi bem sua duvida? uma confusão só, nesse caso você implementa interface nas classes é igual em C#.

Comment: Não sei C#, mas quando dava implements em uma interface no Java, vinha para mim métodos delegados automaticamente.

Comment: se você está falando de métodos já implementados a abordagem é classe `abstract`? seria isso.?

Comment: Sim, também, mas que receba parâmetros e qualquer classe que herdar a interface, tenha métodos já delegados sem eu precisar delegar, porque se eu fizer isso, não vai cumprir o trabalho do script interno, mas é eu que vou fazer esse trabalho.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo na sua pergunta, explicando a funcionalidade, eu estou querendo entender aonde você quer chegar, acho eu (achometro) que você precisa de um classe `abstract` com métodos já implementados ou herança em um classe base ... !!!

Comment: Deixei um exemplo no final \o/

Comment: Você precisa implementar um método independente o que seja, então, no caso tem que ser uma classe `abstract` ou até um classe base fazendo herança vendo de longe acho que é isso.

Comment: Tem como exemplificar?

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://www.codepile.net/pile/AzWqV1nJ mas, eu não tenho certeza que seja isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89863/discussion-between-system-and-virgilio-novic).

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem, você tem que esperar o C# 8 que terá isto chama-se [Default Interface Methods](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md). Se não puder esperar terá que implementar os métodos nas classes, não tem jeito.

O que dá para fazer se é tudo a mesma implementação é criar uma classe estática com os métodos implementados, aí em cada classe na implementação do método você apenas chama o método estático, repassando os parâmetros recebidos, desta forma está delegando a execução é não precisa repetir o código, além do que se mudar o método estático reflete na execução de todas as classes. Esta é a mesma solução que tinha que fazer no Java até a versão 7.